# Quiz Database Schema para MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

```
Users: [{
    - email
    - senha
    - quiz_criado: [id: 1], // ref: Quiz (array com id)
    - quiz_respondido: [{
        id: 1 , // ref: Quiz
        question_respondido: [{
            question_id
            opcao_escolhida
        }]          
    }] 
}]
Quiz: [{
    - quiz_id
    - nome
    - descricao
    - questions: [{
        - question_id
        - question_text
        - type // pode ser uma escolha ou multipla escolha
        - correct_anwsers // a resposta correta
    }]
}];
```

Quiz:

- Terá todos os Quizzes criados por usuários.

Users:

- Poderá criar um Quiz ou vários Quizzes;
- Poderá responder vários Quizzes de outros usuários.

É melhor criar tudo em um Schema? Existe algo que possa ser melhorado no esquema que criei?

Answer (score 0):

O design do schema no mongo deve levar em conta principalmente a seguinte pergunta: **como você vai acessar os dados?**

Considerando que você vai listar os quizes, sem buscar o usuário é melhor usar duas collections mesmo. Não seria interessante buscar os dados do usuário toda vez que você vai listar as quizes. Se fosse uma lista dos quizes favoritos do usuário, por exemplo, faria mais sentido incorporar.

Uma preocupação que pode surgir é sobre as respostas do usuário. Fazendo a pergunta que falei no início: eu preciso de todas as respostas de quizes, quando carregar o usuario? Quem sabe no incio da aplicação isso não seja um problema, mas depois de um tempo essa lista pode ficar grande. Poderia manter nessa lista respostas recentes do usuário, e arquivar respostas antigas em uma collection separada. Poderia excluir respostas depois de um intervalo de tempo (pra isso precisaria de uma data da resposta).